# open corrupt tar file with python

Tags: python, corrupt, tarfile

I am downloading tar files from a ftp server with the help of python. However, now I am facing problems and getting the error "ReadError: unexpected end of data". I assume my file got corrupted. I can open the files outside python with the comment 'wget' inside the terminal, however I would like to only stick to python. This is my code:

```
os.chdir(aod_ipng)
[urlretrieve('%s%s'%(url_ipng,x),'%s'%(x)) for x in ari]

for i in range(len(ari)):
    fileName = '%s'%(ari[i])
    ind = save_ipng[i].index('IVAOT')
    h5f = save_ipng[i][ind:]
    tfile = tarfile.open(fileName,'r|')
    for t in tfile:
        if t.name == '%s'%h5f:
            f = tfile.extract(t)
```

- ari is a string array that holds several names of tar files that needs to be downloaded.
- h5f is the name of the specific h5.gz file that needs to be extracted from the tar file 
  Let me know if you need more information regarding my code!

Comment: Make sure that you actually download a tar file. And then make sure your code finishes downloading the whole file.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Do you have any tricks for that (besides a good internet connection)? How do I make sure my code finishes downloading the whole file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reliable downloads of large files over bad connections is not easy. If [http range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) requests are supported then you can resume the download on broken connections.

A good start is to use the requests library and [read the remote file as a stream](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content).
However disconnects and resumes might still have to be handled by you.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests) for how to use that API

But please make sure that the file is indeed a tar. You can use [libmagic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) for file format detection.

That file extension suggests a gzip not a tar.

```
import gzip
f = gzip.open('h5.gz', 'rb')
file_content = f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look! :-) Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

"ReadError: unexpected end of data"

This means that your file is shorter than expected, so it is not fully downloaded.

`wget` does not open tar files, it downloads files.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, I still get the same error if I try to open the specific tar file when it is completely downloaded. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Download the full file.